# Save ggplot object as image in the environment as object/value

Tags: r, image-processing, ggplot2

I have a ggplot object. Let's call it `plot`. I would like to convert it to png format, but I don't want to save it to a file on my local drive. I'm trying to work with that png object but I want to keep everything in the environment. Everything I've found, including `ggsave`, appears to force one to save the image as a file on the local drive first. I know image files can be stored as values, but I can't seem to get over the "save as" image and "import" image steps.

Here's some code for repoducibility:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- as.data.frame(Titanic)
gg <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Survived, y = Freq))
plot <- gg + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Now, I'd like to convert `plot` to a png to `png` without having to save it to a file. Something like:

```
png <- save.png(plot)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What type of object do you want to end up with? For example, if you save a ggplot as a png file and then load it (say, with `png::readPNG()`), you get an array of four matrices, three for the RGB color channels and one for alpha (transparency). Is that the kind of object you want to work with, or something else?

Comment: @eipi10 I'm not sure how to answer that. I'm using `magick` to work with images. I looked at an image I have in my environment and it provides the following output in the console, along with the image in the viewer:
`>image
>  format width height colorspace matte filesize density
>1    PNG   360     47       sRGB  TRUE     8841   72x72`

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks for your help! I figured out the answer and I couldn't have done it without your direction.

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with a similar issue and followed @eipi12 approach of using `magick`. The code bellow should work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

ggsave_to_variable <- function(p, width = 10, height = 10, dpi = 300){
  pixel_width  = (width  * dpi) / 2.54
  pixel_height = (height * dpi) / 2.54

  img <- magick::image_graph(pixel_width, pixel_height, res = dpi)

  on.exit(utils::capture.output({
    grDevices::dev.off()}))
  plot(p)

  return(img)
}


p <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = 1:100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_line()

my_img <- ggsave_to_variable(p)

my_img %>% 
  magick::image_write("my_img.png")
```